# revised background image comparison

Tags: java, android

i know the brainy people wont like my petty questions but im trying to learn

I,m trying to make a pairs game i have been using int so far on my apps but this game needs a different approach ive created the pairs game with ints but confusing code and a floor that pushing same button twice will delete the pair as below ive been trying with tags the code all looks clean as in no errors

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//added Tag here for the if (pic2.getTag()==(beck)); 
 Tag beck;
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final ImageButton pic1 = (ImageButton )     findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);         
final ImageButton pic2 = (ImageButton )     findViewById(R.id.imageButton2); 

     pic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()       { 
 public void onClick(View v) {  
     pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);
     pic1.setTag(R.drawable.becks);
 if (pic2.getTag() == pic1.getTag()){            
     pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}     
    }});    

     pic2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                            
 public void onClick(View v) {       
     pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);
     pic2.setTag(R.drawable.becks);

     if (pic1.getTag() == pic2.getTag()){
    pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
    }
    }});    
    }}
```

ive tried since my original post to work out how to do ive shown code for 2 buttons all i want to do is compare and make invisible after the second button is clicked

```
if (pic1.getTag().equals(pic2.getTag())){
    pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }
```

the .equals crashes the app

```
     pic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {  
  public void onClick(View v) {  
     pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);
     pic1.setTag(beck);
 if (pic2.getTag()==(beck));{            
     pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}     
     }});
```

this works with or without semi but both buttons dissapear when either button clicked

```
if (pic1.getTag()==(pic2.getTag())){
    pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }
```

this changes the image but the buttons don,t disappear when second image clicked trying to not use ints if possible

this line works with comma to

```
 if (pic1.getTag()==(pic2.getTag()))
 if (pic1.getTag()==(pic2.getTag()));
```

with effect of both button disappear on 1 click of either button dread moving to the else if  lol 
Also can a Tag be removed if the pair of images compared if false eg
if no match remove the button tag  and reset all remaining images to Default image as when i put all 24 buttons on  i need a reset method 
i,m finding the semi colon at end of if statement has different effects to not having can anyone point correct way when and when not to use semi colons

Comment: Why don't you set tags that correspond to the backgrounds of the views. Then check them for equality. In the way used above you are comparing an ImageButton with an Integer.

Comment: 1. Why unaccept my answer!? It's still correct. 2. Don't delete your original post! People have no idea what the first question was 3. Don't edit my answer! It will be rejected 4. If you compare integers or string or whatever, it doesn't matter! You need to understand what you are actually doing first. 5. Your edit is completely incomprehensible! 6. Look at my original answer. Again, it still is the way to go. This site is for specific questions. Your question now goes far beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tags for saving your image-id:

```
pic1.setTag(R.drawable.becks);
pic2.setTag(R.drawable.becks);
```

You can then check and compare those by calling `getTag()` on the buttons that have been clicked:

```
public boolean isMatch(View x, View y) {
  return x.getTag() == y.getTag();
}
```

Comment: Well actually I already gave you all you need. I tried to make it clearer in the edit (without commenting on your code quality though). This is as simple as it gets, try to understand since this really is the basics.

Comment: i have apoligised in advance and we all have to start somewhere apreciated and ill try tidy up im begginer

Comment: Yes but you do have to put in a minimum of effort. The problems you are running into now are not related to your question on how to compare the background-drawables of two image buttons. I guarantee you everything you need for that particular problem is in my code example. The rest is learning to code, something only you can do.

Comment: so is thise site for begginers then im trying to code but im only using net to do research and its not much help code is always interacted with summit else i like to learn a line in plain way then impliment it myself and your code is very helpfull ive changed images using the tag you showed im chuffed at that does this make the images into an int if so can i compare as in if pic1.int == pic2.int{} dont know if thats writen right but if this is possible i can achieve ??? again sorry for messy i will improve

Comment: 'R.drawable.becks' is the ID of your drawable, and that's an int. You don't change that. All you do is use this value to tag your ImageButtons additionally (!), and then use the tags to compare two buttons. You still need to call 'setBackgroundResource()'. So after 'setTag(R.drawable.becks)', all you do is 'if (pic1.getTag()==R.drawable.becks)', instead of just using 'pic1 ==R.drawable.becks'. That's it, I can't help you further. Keep it up, you'll get there. If you got it plz mark this answer as accepted so it's not an open question anymore.

Comment: got it the tag thing really helped add a hidden name to button witch is an int (the Tag) then compares if both have same hidden name in long winded way i got there cheers how do i make the question answered and can i reward you for your help